# Empty query no matter what

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a Table with `ID,FRNZ,MSTR,TES,DEN,PRT` columns that are :

> - ID = id
> - FRNZ = our suppliers
> - MSTR = 2 digit code for catalouges
> - TES = CODE to search
> - DEN = name of the object
> - PRT = price

For every CODE there are 3 rows (articles:one suit one jacket one trousers). I want to display all 3 rows, with all details from the search of the code. I made up this code but i recieve a error.

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query  on line 20

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in line 20
```

**And my code is**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
$TES=$_POST['name']; 
$db=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","") or die ('I cannot connect  to the database because: ' . mysqli_error());
 $mydb=mysqli_select_db($db,"prices");
 $sql=`SELECT * FROM PRICES WHERE TES LIKE '%" . $TES . "%' `;
 mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$TES);
 $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error().'<br>'.$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysqli_error())){ 
          $FRNZ=$row['FRNZ']; 
          $MSTR=$row['MSTR']; 
          $TES=$row['TES']; 
          $DEN=$row['DEN'];
          $PRT=$row['PRT'];
  }
 echo "<ul>\n"; 
  echo "<li>" . "Furnizor :" .$FRNZ . " Mostrar :" . $MSTR ." Cod tesatura :" .$TES . "Denumire :" . $DEN ."Pret :".$PRT . " </a></li>\n"; 
  echo "</ul>"; 

}
}

else{
echo  "<p>Te rog scrie codul de tesatura</p>";}
?>
```

Comment: Remove the ticks `\`` in your query and replace them with quotes. Plus, `mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$TES);` is in the wrong spot, and you should also be assigning a variable to it.

Comment: Replace `$TES=$_POST['name'];` with `$TES=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['name']);` and get rid of `mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$TES);` you're doing twice the work for nothing. As for `mysqli_error()` well, pass DB connection to it. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Well caught @Fred-ii-, more coffee for me. ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard You'd be surprised as to what a "caffè macchiato" will do instead of the regular *run of the mill* cup 'o java will do ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't know why you deleted your answer though. You should just make the other changes/edit. I'd say that would pretty much cover it.

Comment: I edited as you said and still getting the error. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: I do drink that wonderful Cajun blend of coffee with chicory @Fred-ii- Dark, robust, not bitter. I have a significant caffeine problem though - it has zero effect. I just use it as an excuse ;-)

Comment: Check my answer below for the editing of `$sql` @Cein - you did everything that Fred suggested, you just missed a little bit.

Comment: That little bit was `mysqli_error($db) ` ?

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be in your `while` loop. Having `mysqli_error($db)` in the query alone will pick up any errors found.

Comment: However, why `if(isset($_GET['go'])){`? You'll need to show us why and how you're using a GET with a POST method.

Comment: Ok now i only got `Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query on line 19 ` witch is `$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db).'<br>'.$sql);`

Comment: This is the form in witch we are trying to search from 
`<form  method="post" action="index.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
       <input  type="text" name="name" placeholder="codul de tesatura"> 
       <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Cauta"> 
     </form> `

Comment: Place `$TES=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['name']);` below `$mydb=mysqli_select_db($db,"prices");` and check Jay's answer below.

Comment: By the way, is both your database and table called "prices"? One is in uppercase while the other's in lowercase.

Comment: Yes, both my database and table are called prices. Both are lowercase in phpmyadmin . 
I did all edits and when i search for 1949 ( witch i know is there ) i receive :
`Unknown column '%1949%' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM PRICES WHERE TES LIKE `%1949%`  `

Comment: Finally working ! Thank you @Fred -ii-

Comment: Why do you have ticks `\`` to the left and right of `%" . $TES . "%` in your edited code/question? Did you not copy/paste Jay's code in his answer below? It doesn't contain ticks, but single quotes `'`.

Comment: One more question still. I want to display all 3 rows regarding the code. The application as it sits just displays first one.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to php and even newer to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please don't add questions to your original question after an answer has been given and seen by many others already. I have performed a rollback to your originally posted question/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the backticks and quoting on your query. You have -

```
$sql=`SELECT * FROM PRICES WHERE TES LIKE "%" . $TES . "%" `;
```

It should be -

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM PRICES WHERE TES LIKE '%" . $TES . "%' ";
```

You should only have to check for a query error once which you do when you run the query, change this -

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysqli_error())){
```

to this -

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['go'])){` is a bit unclear too. I've asked the OP to provide more info on this.

Comment: Ok this is finally working ! Thanks @Jay Blanchard and Fred -ii- 
Sorry for probabbly this is a really begginer mistake but this is my 1st ever php application ! Thank you again !

Comment: One more question still. 
I want to display all 3 rows regarding the code. The application as it sits just displays first one.

Comment: You need to move your echo into the `while` loop. It sits just outside of it.